# Django: How to mention number of process? like how it is done with Flaks

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework, python-multithreading, flask-restful

I am trying to create a simple Fibonacci web service with 
* Django and
* Flask

I am using **djangorestframework** and **flask_restful** 
I am doing this to make some comparison.

with Flask I am able to specify 
the number of process or 
to use threading etc. with Api in flask_restful

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response, jsonify
from flask_restful import abort, Resource, Api, reqparse
api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(Test, '/test/')

app.run(port=1234, host='0.0.0.0', threaded=True) #processes=50)
```

My question, how to specify the same in django rest framework?
From the docs I am not able to find a straight forward answer, yet..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because it's two different matters.
Django only provides a development server which obviously is for development and single thread/process.

If you want to tune the number of process, you'll need to run the Django project through gunicorn / uwsgi / mod_wsgi / ..., each of those lets you tune the process / threads.

Comment: thank you, I keep getting directed to uWSGI, mod_wsgi, gunicorn. 
I was searching for an answer withing django rest framework... and move on only if there is no option at all.

Comment: The development server is multi-threaded, unless you use the `--nothreading` flag.

Comment: @Raghav DRF is built on top of Django, so whatever applies to Django in terms of deployment will apply for DRF as well.

Comment: @knbk `--nothreading` flag should be mentioned where?

you mean `--nothreading` with either one of the mod_wsgi, uWSGI or gunicorn ??

Comment: @Raghav It's a [flag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-runserver-nothreading) for the development server, i.e. `python manage.py runserver --nothreading`. You usually don't want to use the flag, unless you're debugging concurrency issues.

Comment: @knbk : thank you, i get your point now ` --nothreading         Tells Django to NOT use threading.` this is from manage.py runserver flags. Ok. Now... If I can tell Django NOT use threading, is there a way for me to tell it to use threading or use so many process ? if I have perceived your answer incorrectly - kindly explain and help. Thank you

Comment: @Raghav Django will use threading by default if you just use `python manage.py runserver`. It will always use multi-threading _unless_ you use the `--nothreading` flag. Like Linovia said, it does not support multiple processes.

Comment: @Linovia thank you and yes I understand the DRF is on top of Django.. thank you.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Run the Django project through uwsgi or mod_wsgi.